# How was it decided that this question is non-notable?

Tags: discussion, notability, close-reasons

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/22831/5582

> This question is basically non-notable...

As far as I can tell, it meets our standards of notability.

Comment: Side note: Vote to reopen if you disagree.

Comment: Well i do disagree, but the assertion of non-notability suprised me so much that im checking that i am not missing something first.

Comment: it's *basically* non-notable, meaning it's fundamentally equivalent to it. While it's not enough to close a question, the low quality and the bad answers most definitely *are*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a community deleted question by a user who left.